# Calling method to another method in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have lots of database queries and I would like to use some methods to not repeat my code. I would like to call methods in other defined methods but it doesn't work

I'm getting such error:

```
    class Main:
  File "d.py", line 20, in Main
    for word in getUserWords("SELECT users.mail, field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_.field_what_word_are_you_looking__value, users.uid FROM users INNER JOIN field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_ ON users.uid = field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_.entity_id"):
TypeError: getUserWords() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

my code

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
Class Main:


    def connect(self):
        con = mdb.connect('***', '*****', '****', '***', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        return con

    def cursor(self):
        cursor = self.connect.cursor()
        return cursor()

    def getUserWords(self, sql):
        self.sql = sql
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.connect.commit()
        self.connect.close()
        return data

    for word in getUserWords("SELECT users.mail, field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_.field_what_word_are_you_looking__value, users.uid FROM users INNER JOIN field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_ ON users.uid = field_data_field_what_word_are_you_looking_.entity_id"):
        print word
```

Comment: where is your class for being able to use self?

Comment: class is missing for self.

Comment: After I added a class I get an error: getUserWords() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: All you have here are a bunch of function definitions that look like they want to be methods but are not, since they are not in a class.  Try adding a class definition, then place the methods below it, indented.

Comment: Sigh.  Please post the code.  No one reading this has the slightest idea what you're trying.

Comment: ``getUserWords`` takes just one argument and you are feeding more than one argument.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is possibly the most useless description of a problem. What happens ?

Comment: I suggest either editing this post to show the real code (including the class definition), or else deleting it and trying again with a new one.  This is pretty hopeless at this point.

Comment: I added class but I still get such error: getUserWords() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Ok, so you now have a class with methods, but mixed in with that is some code which is executed when the class is defined, before you have a class instance.  Why?  That `for` loop makes no sense where it is.  Either put it inside a method, or else take it out of the class.  In either case, you need to call `getUserWords` as a method, rather than as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler example:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.foo = "bar"
   def function1(self,x):
      self.function2(x)
   def function2(self,y):
      print y

bar = Foo()
bar.function1(3) # calls function1 which in turn calls function2 which prints out 3
bar.function2(4) # calls function 2 directly.
```

The main takeaway to answer your question:

If you have a class function, it has a first argument which is by convention self.  If you call that class function on an instance (as in bar.function2), the self is implicit.  If you call that class function from within the class (as when function1 calls function2), you need to do self.functionname, which again implicitly passes the self argument.

Answer (score 0):

First point: instanciate your class and call `getUserWords()` on your instance:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
class Main:
    # snip


m = Main() 
sql = your_sql_here
for word in m.getUserWords(sql):
    print word
```

Second point: your implementation of `Main` is flawed.

```
Class Main:
    def connect(self):
        # this will open a new connection on each and every call

        con = mdb.connect('***', '*****', '****', '***', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        return con

    def cursor(self):
        # this will 
        # 1. create a new connection on every call - which will
        #    never be closed since you don't keep a reference
        #    on it so you can close it
        # 2. create a new cursor on every call 
        cursor = self.connect.cursor()

        # and this one will raise a TypeError 
        # => "'Cursor' object is not callable"
        return cursor() 
        # so I assume your real code is :
        return cursor

    def getUserWords(self, sql):
        # assigning sql to self is totally useless here
        self.sql = sql

        # so (assuming self.cursor returns the cursor and not 
        # the call to the cursor), this will:
        # - open a new connection
        # - create a new cursor
        # - execute the sql
        # - and discards eveything (cursor and connection)
        #   without closing them 
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)

        # now we 
        # - open a second connection (without closing the first)
        # - create a second cursor
        # - call .fetchall() on it, which will raise a  
        #   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()

        # we're not making it until this part because of
        # the above error, but if we did, this would:
        # - create yet a third connection and call .commit()
        #   on it - which in this case would mainly be a no-op
        #   since we have nothing to commit
        self.connect.commit()

        # and finally create a fourth connection and close it
        # immediatly - note that this will be the only one that
        # gets closed <g>
        self.connect.close()
        return data
```

A fixed version of your code could look something like this:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

class Main(object):

    def __init__(self, connection_data):
        self._connection_data = connection_data.copy()
        self._connection_data.update(charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self._db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if self._db is None:
            self._db = mdb.connect(**self._connection_data)
        return self._db

    def cursor(self):
        return self.db.cursor()

    def execute(self, sql):
        cursor = self.cursor()
        cursor.execute(self.sql)
        for row in cursor:
            yield row
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close() 


    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self._db.close()
        except:
            # either it's not set or it's already closed
            pass


m = Main(db="***", user="***", passwd="***")
for w in m.getUserWords(your_sql_here):
    print w
```